# How to correct the rule 'Operator overloads have named alternates' in c#

Tags: c#, sonarqube

As the operator overloading (operator> and operator<) violates the rule [Operator overloads have named alternates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182355%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the operator > and < require an alternative method Compare, however, since there can only be one Compare method, what should the signature of that method be?

for example, I have:

```
public static bool operator >(XXX lhs, XXX rhs)
```

and

```
public static bool operator <(XXX lhs, XXX rhs)
```

How to provide a compare method to behave the same as both greater to and less than operators?

Edit:

The `int Compare()` only returns positive (greater than), negative (less than) and 0 (equal), what about in my overloaded operator there is a >= operator, which means my Compare method should handle (greater to or equal to) sinario as well

What about there are >, < >= and <= four overloaded operators?

Comment: Take a look at the IComparable interface, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx, there is also a generic version, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx. public int CompareTo(XXX other) { .... }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static int Compare(XXX lhs, XXX rhs);
```

*Return value:*

- Less than zero
  *lhs* is less than *rhs*.
- Zero
  *lhs* equals *rhs*.
- Greater than zero
  *lhs* is greater than *rhs*.

*Examples:*

- [DateTime.Compare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx)
- [Decimal.Compare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.compare.aspx)

*Usage:*

```
// operator            // named alternative
   x < y                  Compare(x, y) < 0
   x <= y                 Compare(x, y) <= 0
   x > y                  Compare(x, y) > 0
   x >= y                 Compare(x, y) >= 0
```

Implementing [IComparable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) is also a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, what about there are also >= and <= in the overloaded operator?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Can you say it with different words please?

Comment: Sure, I mean the int Compare() only returns positive (greater than), negative (less than) and 0 (equal), what about in my overloaded operator there is a >= operator, which means my Compare method should handle (greater to or equal to) sinario as well.

Comment: I've added usage examples for the Compare method.

Answer (score 1):

You have one Compare method, and the return value determines whether the 2 operands are equal (0), or if x is less than y, or if x is greater than y.

Check out the [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) method , for instance.

Comment: String.Compare is probably not a good example, because String does not have < > operators. But the method signature is the same.